# How do I make IAM calls from the AWS javascript SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

We want to use the IAM module of the AWS Javascript SDK, documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html). We follow the basic instructions, but when trying to instantiate a **new AWS.IAM()** object, it is not found.

We are using the standard library from https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/, and that seems to be the issue - it does not include the IAM module.

Is there a way to tell the SDK to load the IAM module? or maybe a different method to get the IAM module to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IAM module is not included in the "standard" package hosted by Amazon.
Therefore, you should custom build the library that you require.

Here are the steps you need to take:

Get the SDK code from Amazon:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js
$ cd aws-sdk-js/
aws-sdk-js$ git checkout v2.1.28 # if you want a specific version
```

The build process is using node; do **npm install** to ensure you have the tools and dependencies installed (and you need node to be installed, of course).

Now, suppose you want to build a library with support for S3, STS and IAM. Use this command line:

```
aws-sdk-js$ node dist-tools/browser-builder.js s3,sts,iam > aws-sdk-s3-sts-iam.js
```

You can use any naming convention that works for you, but we find the aforementioned most helpful if you use different custom builds.

If you want to minify the custom made library for your release, use the following command line instead (it sets the proper environment variable for node to use):

```
aws-sdk-js$ MINIFY=1 node dist-tools/browser-builder.js s3,sts,iam > aws-sdk-s3-sts-iam.min.js
```

If you care much for the size of the library or you chose to host the Amazon js anyway (maybe you have it bundled with the rest of your stuff), it is probably a good idea to use this process anyway, and only include the libraries you actually need. The savings won't necessarily be big - because there is the shared code that is included anyway - but you might end up saving something. For instance, the above example (that happens to be what we use for one of our projects) reduced the total size from ~300K to ~200K, after adding IAM that we needed (S3 and STS are included in the hosted build).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the "hosted build", which doesn't contains IAM:

> Although all services are supported in the browser version of the SDK, not all of the services are available in the default hosted build (using the script tag provided above). A list of services in the hosted build are provided in the "Working With Services" section of the browser SDK guide, including instructions on how to build a custom version of the SDK with extra services.

[Supported Services](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/index.html#Supported_Services)